# I installed Linux on a partition and now I don't know how to boot it

Tags: boot

Today I installed Ubuntu on to a pre-existing partition (I also made a swap partition during the installation) and when my machine went to restart, my screen went dark and did nothing, I did wait. There was power going to the machine.

I did a forced restart but now I have no clue how to boot to the partition that I have Ubuntu on. I have Windows 7, by the way. I have poked around my BIOS settings and I didn't see anything in the boot tab about choosing a partition to boot off of.

Comment: what you are getting at the booting time , black screen then press shift key at booting and then you will get grub menu and then choose recovery mode and choose failsafeX mode . I hope you will get something and by the way what kind of VGA  drivers you got ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dowload Easybcd software it is free for home user and install it.
open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click and selcet "swap partition" in it after that click on edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting.

Download here:http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

try this tool, its easy , free and smart for dual booting.
I am also using.

Comment: Trying this out now. Are you sure that I set it to the swap partition and not the Ubuntu one? I just did that and it did nothing.

Comment: Also to, what type do I set the new linux entry as? There's Grub, Grub 2, Wubi, ect.

Comment: At new linux entry you should try "GRUB 2" is will automatic detect you ubuntu loader, and swap partition.

Comment: if swap partition is not working after rebooting system , then try ubuntu partition instead of swap , hope it will help full for you.

Comment: Yup that worked out for me! Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help.